# Is there a book that details what the popes said against reformation leaders?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, papacy, resource-request, reformation

Can anyone recommend a book that have all the declarations, laws, statements, etc of popes during the times of reformers like Tyndale, Luther, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Denzinger's [*Sources of Catholic Dogma*](http://denzinger.patristica.net/denzinger/) (*Enchiridion symbolorum, definitionum et declarationum de rebus fidei et morum*) collects most of the major dogmatic definitions; it "traces the development of doctrine and Dogma in the Catholic Church from its earliest times."